# Can I host a MineBuilder server?

Tags: wifi, server, android, networking

Is it possible to host a minebuilder server on a raspberry pi? (B Model)
Server Program: http://www.space-walrus.com/topic/53/minebuilder-server-program

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess. Since it works well on linux, you should be able to run it on Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi's make great servers and as dastaan has said since it works on Linux there is no reason why the Pi should not be able to run it. Just remember the model B has limited CPU power, so maybe a Raspberry Pi 2 would be better suited to the task.

Comment: Can you give me more information how I can install it on the raspberry, including installing the java stuff etc.

Comment: I'll look into it but you will have to wait a day

Comment: No problem, I have time:-)

Comment: give me a week been busy as of late sorry